# Accessing Emergency Contact Info via RingCentral REST API

Tags: ringcentral

Is there any way to access the emergency contact info? I cannot find it in the API Reference but it is available in the RingCentral Online Account Portal as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emergency address contact info is available in the Device Info `emergencyServiceAddress` property.

The Device Info object with this property is available in both the account and extension APIs:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/device/{deviceId}
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/device/{deviceId}
```

To get a list of `deviceId` values to query, call the Device List APIs:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/device
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/device
```

The Device List APIs do not include the `emergencyServiceAddress` so you need to use this to find the `deviceId` to get the info for the specific device.

The `emergencyServiceAddress` property looks like the following:

```
"emergencyServiceAddress": {
    "street": "20 Davis Drive",
    "city": "Belmont",
    "state": "CA",
    "country": "US",
    "zip": "94402",
    "customerName": "John RingForce"
},
```

You can also update the emergency service address by using the Update Device endpoint:

```
PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/device/{deviceId}

{
    "emergencyServiceAddress": {
        "street": "19 Davis Drive",
        "city": "Belmont",
        "state": "CA",
        "country": "US",
        "zip": "94402",
        "customerName": "John RingForce"
    }
}
```

Some demo code for this is available for Go in the repo for the [`go-ringcentral` SDK](https://github.com/grokify/go-ringcentral):

https://github.com/grokify/go-ringcentral/blob/master/examples/e911_address/e911_address.go